# Cannot find 'LazyVGrid' in scope

Tags: swiftui, ios14

After macOS Big Sur 11 beta 9, has been released, **LazyVGrid** and **GridItem** structs are no longer available.

I receive, on Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300), the following compiler errors:

***"Cannot find 'LazyVGrid' in scope"
"Cannot find 'GridItem' in scope"***

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's working with latest Xcode 12.2 Beta 3.